NonRepeatableRequestException occurs when setting ProxyProperties
I'm using Axis2 (1.8) and Java8 ,HttpCLient4.5
NonRepeatableRequestException occurs when setting ProxyProperties
I am writing code like below
Options options = stub._getServiceClient().getOptions();

HttpTransportProperties.ProxyProperties props = new ProxyProperties();
props.setProxyName("http://sample.co.jp");
props.setPassWord("Password");
props.setProxyPort(8090);
props.setUserName("UserName");
options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.PROXY, props);

Please give me an idea how to fix it
